# Have list of data.frames, want means across list elements

Tags: r

I have a list of `data.frame`s structured like so:

```
mylist <- list(x=data.frame(group=1:3, x=c(43, 29, 49)),
               y=data.frame(group=1:3, x=c(29, 39, 11)),
               z=data.frame(group=1:3, x=c(20, 38, 98)))
```

So each `data.frame` has two columns. I want to get the mean of these `data.frame`s by row. So the first mean would be `(43+29+20)/3`, the second `(29+39+38)/3`, and the third `(49+11+98)/3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 Reduce(`+`, mylist)/length(mylist)
 #  group        x
 #1     1 30.66667
 #2     2 35.33333
 #3     3 52.66667
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(mylist)[, list(x=mean(x)), group]
 #  group        x
 #1:     1 30.66667
 #2:     2 35.33333
 #3:     3 52.66667
```

Or

```
 library(tidyr)
 library(dplyr)
 unnest(mylist) %>%
          group_by(group) %>%
          summarise(x=mean(x))
```

Based on the output showed in the OP's post

```
 (43+29+20)/3
 #[1] 30.66667

 (29+39+38)/3
 #[1] 35.33333

 (49+11+98)/3
 #[1] 52.66667
```

Comment: That first one doesn't work, as it outputs a single number, where I want three numbers. One for each row

Answer (score 2):

Playing with `dim`

```
rowMeans(simplify2array(unlist(mylist, rec=F))[,c(F,T)])
```

or, explicitly

```
rowMeans(`dim<-`(unlist(mylist), dim(mylist[[1]])*c(1, length(mylist)))[,c(F, T)])
# [1] 30.66667 35.33333 52.66667
```